# spring REST response json format

Tags: json, spring, rest, jpa

I am working on building a REST API and one of the concern I have is with the attributes for creating and updating the attributes. My `DTO` class have a ton of attributes and object references. I need to specify a subset of attributes while creating and updating but want to send all the details while retrieval i.e when `GET` request.

- I can write another class with the modifiable attributes and expose it to the clients but is there any other way to do this? Is it a good
- Is it a good practise to make other attributes `(insertable=false, updatable=false)` as I am using JPA.

What is the recommended/standard way of handling this requirement.